# Is it possible to display full screen ad directly in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, fullscreen, ads

I want to know that is it possible to display full screen ad directly in iPhone?as i don't want to display small banner ad and wants direct full screen ad.
and if yes then how?
For that what to use i mean how can i show it with iAd or AdWhirl or AdMob or other?
Thanks.

Comment: Your users will hate your app, and quite possibly you, if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can by using rich media iads but they are supported only on iPad & ios 4.3.Check the documentation. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html